# whats the advantages to use react js in asp.net core project?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I want to build an accounting application by asp.net core and I want to know is that better to use react js for my app UI or there is no difference? Is that makes my work easier?
(I am new in both asp.net core and react js.)
thanks for answering :)

Comment: [React.js](https://reactjs.org/) is simply a framework for building UI using javascript. There are many other javascript frameworks as well but they all aim to provide a structured way to build UIs. I suggest you try some of the examples from a few of these to see which ones you like.

Answer (score 1):

actually to answer you question it depends on your background on js, if you know js you should test vue.js or react.js but if you don't relax with those frameworks you should test Angular because it uses typescript language that similar to c#.